# Angular2 - Routing is stopped after in deployment mode

Tags: angular, typescript, server, angular2-routing

After building the angular2 application using the command line "ng build",
I  have added the content of the  "dist" file to the server (throw the FTP client) in directory called "CMS".

> The server have website files.
>
> I need to access my angular2 application when i calling the URL like this:
> `http://thewebsiteurlintheserver.com/CMS`

When I  do the last (http://thewebsiteurlintheserver.com/CMS) i got this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'CMS'
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'CMS'

Comment: did you set basepath of your application in angular cli or in index.html

Comment: yes base "<base href="/">" @AniruddhaDas in my index.html

Comment: try base path as `<base href="/CMS">` as your are putting your code under a directory not in the base path `/`

Comment: I tried this, Doesn't work @AniruddhaDas

Answer (score 0):

you should change base href. to `<base href="/CMS/">`

If you use angular cli, you can use this command `ng build --prod --baseHref /CMS/`.

If you do not use angular cli, you can change base href in `index.html`

Comment: Thank You @jong-Hyun Kin